# How to use join function to sum 2 fields in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me to sum the 2 fields and display the results in one box by using JavaScript.

```
var values1 = this.getField("Text6").value.split("\r");
var values2 = this.getField("Text7").value.split("\r");

for(i = 0; i < values1.length  ; i++)
{
values1[i] =  parseInt(values1[i]) + "\n";
values2[i] =  parseInt(values2[i]) + "\n";


this.getField("Text8").value = (values1[i]+values2[i]).join("") ;
}
```

I am getting the following error:
**TypeError: (values1 + values2).join is not a function**

Comment: You mean `[values1[i], values2[i]].join('')`?

Comment: yeah to get the sum of Values 1 and values 2 and display in a box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't join like that, the join method can only be applied on an array.

You can do this:

```
this.getField("Text8").value = [values1[i], values2[i]].join("");
```

But a better way:

```
this.getField("Text8").value = `${values1[i]}${values2[i]}`;
```

EDIT:

If you want to do a sum, you can simply do this:

```
this.getField("Text8").value = values1[i] + values2[i];
```

If you have string instead of a int as values, then you need to cast their values before:

```
this.getField("Text8").value = parseInt(values1[i]) + parseInt(values2[i]);
```

Comment: So here is what I am trying to achieve...Values 1 = 4  value 2 =6 I need to see 10 in textbox 8

Comment: You can use one of the two last code pieces. The first one if you already have integers, the second if your values are string (like "4" & "6")

Comment: var values1 = this.getField("Text6").value.split("\r");
var values2 = this.getField("Text7").value.split("\r");

for(i = 0; i < values1.length  ; i++)
{
values1[i] =  parseInt(values1[i]) + "\n";
values2[i] =  parseInt(values2[i]) + "\n";

this.getField("Text8").value = values1[i] + values2[i];
}   it is not adding still …currently it is displaying last values from value 1 and value 2 in two differnt lines (text8).Nothing above from values 1 and 2

Comment: and if i am using `${values1[i]}${values2[i]}`; it says  SyntaxError: illegal character

Comment: Why are you trying to put "\n" in you values ? You can't do that. If you want to display an integer, you can't mix integer and string. The "\n" formatting won't work as easily. If you need some kind of formatting, you should then build a different HTML layout and use CSS to achieve what you want visually.

Comment: \n I am using because I want to print each record in a new line... ?

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but you are trying to do multiple things at once, and that why your code breaks. I don't say this to be mean or rude, but I recommend you to follow a course / watch video about JavaScript and understand all the basics of it, because you've actually a comprehension problem here. It will help you better understand why you code is wrong and how to fix it. If I give you a full solution now, you will have exactly the same problem on the next line of code you'll write, so it's better for you to go back to the basics first, I think.